# How can I watch multiple variables while debugging without stopping at breakpoints?

Tags: c++, debugging, ide

Suppose I have a complex C++ application that I need to debug with a lot of variables. I wanna avoid using `std::cout` and `printf` approaches (below there's an explaination why).

In order to explain my issue, I wrote a **minimal** example using `chrono` *(This program calculates `fps` of its while cycle over time and increment `i_times` counter until it reaches 10k)*:

```
#include <chrono>

using chrono_hclock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    bool is_running = true;
    float fps;
    int i_times=0;
    chrono_hclock::time_point start;
    chrono_hclock::time_point end;

    while(is_running){
         start = chrono_hclock::now();

         // Some code execution

         end = chrono_hclock::now();

         fps=(float)1e9/(float)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-start).count());
         if(++i_times==10000) is_running=false;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to debug this program and watch for `fps` and `i_times` variables continuosly over time, **without stopping execution**.

Of course I can simply use `std::cout`, `printf` or other means to output variables values redirecting them to `stdout` or a file while debugging and those are OK for simple types, but I have multiple variables which data type are struct-based and it would be creepy, time expensive and code bloating to write instructions to print each one of them. Also my application is a realtime video/audio H.264 encoder streaming with RTSP protocol and stopping at breakpoints means visualizing artifacts in my other decoder application because the encoder can't keep up with the decoder (because the encoder hit a breakpoint).

**How can I solve this issue?**

Thanks and regards!

---

The IDE I'm currently using for developing is **Visual Studio 2019 Community**.

I'm using the **Local Windows Debugger**.

I'm open to using alternative open source IDEs like VSCode or alternative debugging methods to solve this problem and/or to not be confinated into using a specific IDE.

To watch for specific multiple variables in **VS** I use the built-in `Watch` Window. While debugging with `LWD`, I add manually variables by right-clicking them in my source code and click `Add Watch`. Then those are showed in the `Watch` Window *(Debug-Windows-Watch-Watch 1)*:
[image: watch_window_1]

However I can **only** watch this window contents once I hit a breakpoint I set inside the `while cycle`, thus **blocking execution**, so that doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: How about simply writing it to a file after the execution of the while(true) loop? Make some container in which you add those or of which you set the values `container[i_times] = fps;` ?

Comment: One ridiculous solution I used once was to export the layout of my class to CheatEngine and real time watch the compiled executable there. If you feel experimental...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use nonblocking breakpoint. First add the breakpoint. Then click on breakpoint settings or right click and select action.
[image]
Now you add a message like any string that is suggestive for you. And in brackets include the values to show, for instance

```
value of y is {y} and value of x is {x}
```

In the image is shown the value of i when it hits the breakpoint. Check the "Continue code execution" so breakpoint will not block execution. The shape of your breakpoint will change to red diagonal square. You can add also specific conditions if you click the Conditions checkbox.
Now while debugging all these debug messages will be shown in the output window:
[image]
In the above image it is showing the following message:

```
the value of i is {i}
```

By checking the "Conditions" you can add specific conditions, for instance i%100==0 and it will show the message only if i is divisible by 100. 
[image]
This time your breakpoint will be marked with a + sign, meaning it has condition. Now while debugging there will be shown the i only when divisible by 100, so you can restrict the output to some more meaningful cases 
[image]

Comment: I used VS for over a decade, and never notice! I think this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: I tried this method today. It's quick and awesome! I also tried to access a struct with two variables such as AVRational in my project that has num=1 and den=44100 and I got {num=1 den=44100 } in output console, so it can also print member values without having to be explicit. Bounty awarded to you, but just some notes: while debugging with these kind of breakpoints, the program slowed down by a factor of 5-10x due to memory analyzing, also I would like to know if it's possible to extend the output instead of reading ... for more complex structs.

Comment: But I can just type the variables I need, so this solved my task. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The strict answer is "no" but...

I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish.  This could be done by dumping the watched variables into to shared memory which is read by 2nd process.  A watch and a break point in the 2nd would allow you to see the values in Visual Studio without interrupting the original application.

A few caveats:

- UAC must be admin on both sides to open the memory handle
- This wouldn't work with pointers as the 2nd program only has access to the shared memory
- Windows anti-virus went nuts for the first few times I
  ran this but eventually calmed down

Worker application:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

PCWSTR SHARED_MEMORY_NAME = L"Global\\WatchMemory";

struct watch_collection  // Container for everything we want to watch
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
};

using chrono_hclock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    bool is_running = true;
    float fps;
    int i_times = 0;
    chrono_hclock::time_point start;
    chrono_hclock::time_point end;
    HANDLE map_file;
    void* shared_buffer;

    // Set up the shared memory space
    map_file = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(watch_collection), SHARED_MEMORY_NAME);
    if (map_file == NULL)
    {
        return 1;  // Didn't work, bail.  Check UAC level!
    }

    shared_buffer = MapViewOfFile(map_file, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, sizeof(watch_collection));
    if (shared_buffer == NULL)
    {
        CloseHandle(map_file);  // Didn't work, clean up the file handle and bail.
        return 1;  
    }

    // Do some stuff
    while (is_running) {
        start = chrono_hclock::now();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 10000; k++) {
                    watch_collection watches { i = i, j = j, k = k };
                    CopyMemory(shared_buffer, (void*)&watches, (sizeof(watch_collection))); // Copy the watches to the shared memory space

                    // Do more things...
                }
            }
        }

        end = chrono_hclock::now();

        fps = (float)1e9 / (float)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();
        if (++i_times == 1000000) is_running = false;
    }

    // Clean up the shared memory buffer and handle
    UnmapViewOfFile(shared_buffer);
    CloseHandle(map_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Watcher application:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

PCWSTR SHARED_MEMORY_NAME = L"Global\\WatchMemory";

struct watch_collection  // Container for everything we want to watch
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
};


int main()
{
    HANDLE map_file;
    void* shared_buffer;
    bool is_running = true;

    watch_collection watches; // Put a watch on watches

    // Connect to the shared memory
    map_file = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, SHARED_MEMORY_NAME);
    if (map_file == NULL)
    {
        return 1; // Couldn't open the handle, bail.  Check UAC level!
    }

    shared_buffer = MapViewOfFile(map_file, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, sizeof(watch_collection));
    if (shared_buffer == NULL)
    {
        CloseHandle(map_file);
        return 1;
    }

    // Loop forever
    while (is_running)
    { 
        CopyMemory((void*)&watches, shared_buffer, (sizeof(watch_collection)));  
    } // Breakpoint here

    UnmapViewOfFile(shared_buffer);
    CloseHandle(map_file);

    return 0;
}
```